# Transactional annotation does not save on exit

Tags: spring, hibernate, jpa, transactions

I have configured spring jpa with annotation driven. I would expect the following code to persist the changes to the database upon method exist.

```
@Transactional
public Foo changeValue(int id){
    final Foo foo = fooRepository.findOne(id);
    if(foo != null){
       foo.setValue("new value");
       //fooRepository.save(foo);
    }
}
```

`FooRepository` is a `JPARepository` and the foo object is getting fetched so it is managed. Based on what I read about @Transactional **I would expect** that even without the `fooRepository.save(foo)` call the changes in foo's value column in the database would be persisted upon method exist. However, this only happens if I uncomment the call to `fooRepository.save(foo)`

*No exceptions are thrown* and the configuration for the jpa datasource is as below.

```
  <bean id="entityManagerFactory"  class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean"> 
   ...
    <bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager"
    p:entityManagerFactory-ref="entityManagerFactory" />

<tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager" />

<context:component-scan
    base-package="com.example.package.data" />

<jpa:repositories
    base-package="com.example.package.data.repository"
    entity-manager-factory-ref="entityManagerFactory"
    transaction-manager-ref="transactionManager" />
```

Any ideas?

**Update**

I do have a `ContextLoaderListener` and a `DispatcherServlet` but I do not have component scan for both.

```
    <servlet>
    <servlet-name>appServlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>/WEB-INF/spring/appServlet/servlet-context.xml</param-value>
    </init-param>
    </servlet>
    ....
    <listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
    </listener>
```

**Update**

```
    <context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>/WEB-INF/spring/root-context.xml</param-value>

    </context-param>
```

And there I do

```
    <context:component-scan base-package="com.example.package">
 <context:exclude-filter type="regex" 
        expression="com.example.package.data.*" />
 <context:exclude-filter type="regex" 
        expression="com.example.package.web.controller.*" />    
 <context:exclude-filter type="regex" 
        expression="com.example.package.web.service.*" />       
</context:component-scan>
```

And in `servlet-context`

```
<context:component-scan base-package="com.example.package.web" />
```

Comment: I seriously doubt that Spring would automatically save your Entity just because you have modified an attached Entity within a Transaction. Can you give us a reference to any documentation which states that? If you have a look at [this Spring Documentation](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/1.3.0.RELEASE/reference/html/jpa.repositories.html) and in particular the 2.16 Example on that page, then you can see that the code explicitly calls the repository `save` method within the transactional `addRoleToAllUsers` method.

Comment: @DuncanKinnear Spring does not save entities in any situation, it's Hibernate's job to do that.

Comment: Does your non-working example look exactly like this? Or this is a demonstrative short example?

Comment: Do you have both a `ContextLoaderListener` and `DispatcherServlet`? And in both a `<context:component-scan />`? If yes you have 2 instances of the same bean 1 transactional the other isn't and this last one is going to be used.

Comment: @DraganBozanovic yes the non-working example looks like this. I just changed variable names and omitted error handling which is not reached as per my debugging.

Comment: As M. Deinum said, it may be that `changeValue()` is executed in non-transactional context. What does `fooRepository.save(foo)` do? Is it `entityManager.merge()`? If yes, then you may be working with detached `foo` which is just reatached in `fooRepository.save()`, but not dirty-checked at the end of `changeValue()`.

Comment: @DraganBozanovic I am currently unable to check M.Deinum's suggestion. I will tonight. however the fooRepository is just an interface implementing the JPARepository<Foo,Integer>. Given the code above how can it be detached if It is fetched through a JPARepository findOne method?

Comment: It can be detached if `changeValue()` is not executed in transactional context: `fooRepository.findOne()` starts a transaction, reads the entity, commits the transaction, and returns the detached instance.

Comment: @M.Deinum please see my eddid.

Comment: Which config is loaded by the `ContextLoaderListener`?

Comment: @M.Deinum please see my edit. Package web has on more subpackage except for the two I am excluding in the root-context.xml

Comment: And let me guess your `COntextLoaderListener` also contains the `<tx:annotation-driven />`? Judging from the packages your service is loaded by the `DispatcherServlet` and as such not affected by the `<tx:annotation-driven />` hence no shared transaction and no automatic save. I guess the `web.service` needs to be scanned in the root context and not servlet context.

Comment: @M.Deinum Fixed it! Thanks for your help. The solution was to remove the scanning from the DispatcherServlet and scan only in root and in the jpa repository. in fact it doesn't make a difference if the jpa xml (which contains the tx:annotation-driven) is first or not. However there was only ONE tx:annotation-driven. I am still confuse why this happened. Please write a regular reply so I can upvote and accept it. Thanks for all your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have both a `ContextLoaderListener` and `DispatcherServlet` they both load a configuration file.

Judging from your configuration the services are loaded by the `DispatcherServlet` and your `<tx:annotation-driven />` is loaded by the `ContextLoaderListener`. They both create an `ApplicationContext` and as AOP is only applied to the beans in the same context your services will not be transactional (Transaction management is done by using AOP).

As a rule of thumb your `ContextLoaderListener` should contain all shared or global resources (like services, daos, datasources etc.) whereas your `DispatcherServlet` should only contain web related beans like controllers, view resolvers etc.

Answer (score 3):

Your general approach is correct. The changes should get saved and committed on exit of the method. While this approach works great when it works it is a bitch to debug.

Your configuration looks ok to me, so I would double check, that you actually have Spring Beans at your disposal and not some instance that you created simply by calling the constructor.

To verify this, just put a breakpoint at the code point where the annotated method gets called. The bean with the annotated method should NOT by of the class you wrote, but some `ProxySomething` class.

This article also provides some pointers what might be wrong with your setup.